# replacing values in pandas df column with values from another of same row if condition is met

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got a df that I'm trying to clean. In instances where the value in col1 is = 0 I want to replace the 0 with the corresponding value from col2. What's the easiest way to do this?

edit: I got it nevermind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].replace(0, np.nan).fillna(df['col2'])
```

Another way with `mask`:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].mask(df['col1'] == 0, other=df['col2'])
```

Or the opposite with `where`:

```
df['col1'] = df['col1'].where(df['col1'] != 0, other=df['col2'])
```

And with `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['col1'].eq(0), 'col1'] = df['col2']
```

Comment: ended up using this:
df.loc[df['fill'].eq(0),'fill']=df.loc[df['fill'].eq(0),'CitySupplied LotArea']

Comment: You don't need to use a boolean mask for the right side. Check my last proposition.